# Kotlin input as a BigInteger

Tags: input, kotlin, biginteger

I want to read two 50-digit numbers and print their sum, but I can't get input in Kotlin as BigInteger.

1. How can I read Kotlin input as BigInteger?
2. Are there any other way to solve such a problem?

Comment: The same as you would in Java. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Here  `var sum:BigInteger = readLine().toBigInteger()`.
toBigInteger() is an unresolved reference.

Comment: It is unresolved because there is no BigInteger type in Kotlin. You have to use BigInteger of Java.

Comment: @AksharPatel I saw this, but my problem is "How to get a BigInteger input?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it the same way as you would in **Java**:

```
val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
val first = scanner.nextBigInteger()
val second = scanner.nextBigInteger()

print(first + second)
```

**OR** you can use `readLine()` from `kotlin.io`:

```
val first = BigInteger(readLine())
val second = BigInteger(readLine())

print(first + second)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.
Are there any way to use `readLine()` instead of Scanner?